# Class referenced in the layout file, `com.leo.simplearcloader.SimpleArcLoader`, was not found in the project or the libraries

Tags: android-studio

//dependencies: implementation 'com.leo.simplearcloader:simplearcloader:1.0.'

```
 <com.leo.simplearcloader.SimpleArcLoader

                android:visibility="visible"
                android:id="@+id/loader"
                android:layout_centerInParent="true"
                android:layout_width="60dp"
                android:layout_height="60dp">
            
           
 </com.leo.simplearcloader.SimpleArcLoader>
```

Answer (score 0):

make sure your build.gradle(project level) have *maven{}* in repositories, something like this:

```
    repositories {
        google()
        maven { url 'https://jitpack.io' }
        mavenCentral()
        jcenter()
    }
```